# Using information from text file but getting an error saying: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I'm pulling information from my text file that I made in my first method that looks something like this:

12,.,1,H,2,I,1,M,1,H,1,I,1,M,1,H,2,M,1,H,30,M,1,:,13,.

11,.,3,M,1,I,1,:,1,M,2,I,1,:,1,M,1,I,1,H,1,M,1,H,5,M,1,H,4,M,1,I,3,M,1,I,14,M,13,.

I printed this information in a separate text file and made a second method so that I essentially create a string to to locate the number and the symbol and multiply the symbol by the number. It should look something like this:

............HIIMHIMHMMHMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:.............
...........MMMI:MII:MIHMHMMMMMHMMMMIMMMIMMMMMMMMMMMMMM.............

I'm getting this error and I don't know what this means.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at AsciiArtBuilder.numToImageRep(AsciiArtBuilder.java:149)
    at AsciiArtBuilder.main(AsciiArtBuilder.java:50)
```

What I had thought of doing was using a for loop to increase the increments by 2 since my number and my symbol are always on even spots and then locate the first integer to multiply it with the symbol. I know my second method is not in a File format I am trying to figure out the code for it before converting it to printing out the output. I'm so sorry for the messy code I'm still learning in my classes.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public class AsciiArtBuilder
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
File input = new File("AnimeGirl.txt");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);

      File output = new File("newfile.txt");
      Scanner out = new Scanner(output);

      while(sc.hasNextLine())
      {
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
      }

      // This prints out the comma separated list with number of charaters in a new file
      imageToNumRep(input, output);


      // This prints out the same text image using the comma separated list
      File secondOutput = new File("newfile2.txt");
      Scanner secondOut = new Scanner(secondOutput);

      numToImageRep(output, secondOutput);
      }
    }

public static void imageToNumRep(File input, File output) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner (input);
      Scanner out = new Scanner (output);

      FileOutputStream printOut;
      PrintStream file = new PrintStream (new File("newfile.txt"));

      // This while loop reads lines from the file
      try
      {
        printOut = new FileOutputStream("newfile.txt");
        file = new PrintStream(printOut);

        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
          String line = sc.next();
          Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
          String token = lineScan.next();

          int count = 0;
          int placeholder = 0;
          int temp = 0;

          for (int i = 0; i < token.length() - 1 ; i++)
          {
            if (token.charAt(i) == token.charAt(i + 1))
            {
              count++;
              placeholder++;
              temp = count;
            }
            else
            {
              char z = token.charAt(placeholder);
              file.print(  count + 1 + "," + z  + ",");
              placeholder++;
              count = 0;
            }
          }
          file.println(temp + 1 + "," + token.charAt(token.length()-1));
        }
        file.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println("Cannot create file.");
        System.exit(-1);
      }
    }


public static void numToImageRep(File input, File output) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner (input);
      Scanner out = new Scanner (output);

      while (sc.hasNextLine())
      {
        String line = sc.next();
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
        String token = lineScan.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < token.length() - 1; i += 2)
        {
          if (sc.hasNextInt())
          {
            int numInstances = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print(numInstances * token.charAt(i));
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating 3 scanners?

Comment: @drum Even 7 scanners.

Comment: Look at the method `numToImageRep` and try to figure what you are wanting to do. a) `Scanner out` - not used.  b) `Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);` - no idea what you are trying to do.  c) put comments in your code so other people (or yourself) in the future know what you are trying to do  d)  `numInstances * token.charAt(i)` - no idea what you are expecting from this.

Comment: So I took it a step back and just printed for (int i = 0; i < token.length() - 1; i += 2){System.out.print(charAt(i))} and saw that using increments of 2 won't work for this. I switched it back to i++ so I can scan through each one individually. I also noticed that if I scan each individual one it'll take 1 only (i'm assuming cause it thinks its a string) and recognize that as one character and not recognize 12 . Can I use a for loop to go through each position and then use an if statement to locate the first integer and then multiply it by the character located two positions after that?

Comment: Why are you creating `Scanners` for *output* files? This code makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry it makes no sense I'm still new at this... I was given a shell code and my goal is to use File input to create an File output in both of the methods. Scanner sc = new Scanner (input); will call out the initial text file that is needed to examine. I realize file output was listed and not used, but I am working on finishing it at the end of the code. Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line); is used to examine each position of each line in the text file.